# Array permutations while maintaining headings

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains any number of elements, and is allowed to be a multidimensional array, too.  My testing example of such array data is:

```
$arr = array(
         array('Material-A', 'Material-B'),
         array('Profile-A', 'Profile-B', 'Profile-C'),
         array('Thread-A', 'Thread-B'),
         // ... any number of elements
        );
```

From this multidimensional array I need to create a single array that is linear in the following format.

```
$arrFormated = array(
                 'Material-A',
                 'Material-A_Profile-A',
                 'Material-A_Profile-A_Thread-A',
                 'Material-A_Profile-A_Thread-B',
                 'Material-A_Profile-A_Thread-C',
                 'Material-A_Profile-B',
                 'Material-A_Profile-B_Thread-A',
                 'Material-A_Profile-B_Thread-B',
                 'Material-A_Profile-B_Thread-C',
                 'Material-A_Profile-C',
                 'Material-A_Profile-C_Thread-A',
                 'Material-A_Profile-C_Thread-B',
                 'Material-A_Profile-C_Thread-C',
                 'Material-B',
                 'Material-B_Profile-A',
                 'Material-B_Profile-A_Thread-A'
                 // Repeat similar pattern found above, etc...
               );
```

For a recursive function, the best that I've been able to come up with thus far is as follows:

```
    private function showAllElements($arr)
    {
        for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
        {
            $element = $arr[$i];
            if (gettype($element) == "array") {
                $this->showAllElements($element);
            } else {
                echo $element . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this code is no where close to producing my desired results.  The outcome from the above code is.

```
Material-A
Material-B
Profile-A
Profile-B
Profile-C
Thread-A
Thread-B
```

Could somebody please help me with the recursive side of this function so I may get my desired results?

Comment: I think `array('Thread-A', 'Thread-B'),` should be `array('Thread-A', 'Thread-B', 'Thread-C'),` from your desired Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generally recommend thinking about *what* you want to be recursive. You tried to work with the *current element* in every recursion step, but your method needs to look at the *next* array element of the original Array in each recursion step. In this case, it's more useful to pass an index to your recursive function, because the 'current element' (the `$arr` in `showAllElements($arr)`) is not helpful.

I think this code should do it:

```
$exampleArray = array(
         array('Material-A', 'Material-B'),
         array('Profile-A', 'Profile-B', 'Profile-C'),
         array('Thread-A', 'Thread-B','Thread-C'),
         // ... any number of elements
        );

class StackOverflowQuestion37823464{
    public $array;
    public function dumpElements($level = 0 /* default parameter: start at first element if no index is given */){
        $return=[];
        if($level==count($this->array)-1){ 
            $return=$this->array[$level]; /* This is the anchor of the recursion. If the given index is the index of the last array element, no recursion is neccesarry */
        }else{
            foreach($this->array[$level] as $thislevel) { /* otherwise, every element of the current step will need to be concatenated... */
                $return[]=$thislevel;
                foreach($this->dumpElements($level+1) as $stringifyIt){ /*...with every string from the next element and following elements*/
                    $return[]=$thislevel.'_'.$stringifyIt;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
$test=new StackOverflowQuestion37823464();
$test->array=$exampleArray;
var_dump($test->dumpElements());
```

Comment: Your solution is absolutely exactly what I needed.  For what it's worth, I also found this online.  http://ask.amoeba.co.in/php-combinations-of-array-elements/